# How to do SUMIFs in Power BI (CALCULATE/SUM)

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have a table in excel that uses SOMASES, the following formula:

=SUMIF(Table[[#All];[Book Balance Value]];Table[[#All];[Product code]];[@Product])

It sums all the values ​​of Book Balance Value, using the Product Code as a criterion, and the @Product references the product code

But when trying to use it in PowerBI it doesn't work, so I'm using:

CALCULATE(SUM(ODS[Book Balance Value]), ODS[Product code],ODS[Product])

Excel Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47s3d.png)

Power BI [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Ovp.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the equivalent of `SUMIFS` as a DAX expression, try this syntax:

```
SUMIFS = SUMX(
            FILTER('Table',
                        EARLIER([Column1])=[Column1] &&
                        EARLIER([Column3])=[Column3]), 
            [Column2])
```

You can conatenate as many conditions as you want in the `FILTER` expression.  The `EARLIER` function refers to the current row.